# How to make my .exe file trusted by other computers

Tags: windows, python, anti-virus

I've made a simple python program to upload files to a server for people in my company to use (it's a short-term solution for now). The user runs the file and it asks them to choose files, which are then uploaded to a server. My code is here:

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Label, Button
import paramiko
import urllib.parse
import os
from pathlib import Path

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Server Uploader")
        master.resizable(height=False, width=False)
        master.configure(bg="white")

        self.label = Label(master, text="There was a problem connecting to the server. Please try again later or contact me.", fg="black", bg="white")
        self.label.config(font=("Courier", 12))
        self.label.pack()

class SuccessfulUpload:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Successful Upload")
        master.resizable(height=False,width=False)

        self.label = Label(master, text="Upload successful. You can now close this window.")
        self.label.config(font=("Courier, 12"))
        self.label.pack()

#Connect to server using SFTP
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    ssh_client.connect(hostname='hostname',port=portno,username='username',password='password')
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = MyGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
    raise SystemExit

#Ask for user to choose files to upload
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="Choose Files to Upload to the Server", filetypes=(("All Files","*.*"),("PDF Files","*.pdf"), ("Word Files","*.doc*")))
print (root.tk.splitlist(files))

s = ssh_client.open_sftp()
if files == "":
    raise SystemExit

#Define local and remote path for file
for file in files:
    localpath = file
    parts = Path(file).parts
    endpath = parts[-1]
    print(endpath)
    remotepath="/Path/" + endpath
    print(remotepath)
    s.put(localpath,remotepath)

root = Tk()
fin = SuccessfulUpload(root)
root.mainloop()

s.close()
root.destroy()

complete = input("Upload Successful. Press any key to exit.")
```

I converted the .py file into a .exe file using pyinstaller. I then sent it to another computer. First, Windows tried to prevent the program from downloading (understandable), then once allowed to download, Windows tries to stop the program from running - bit annoying but OK. Still, after allowing the program twice through Windows, anti-virus (AVG) still prevents the program from running. To get it to run, I've had to go directly onto the anti-virus and make an exception for my program.

I can't send the program out whilst you have to manually make an exception for it within the anti-virus. Is there any way to make your file more trustworthy for other computers to download and run (without anti-virus completely stopping the program from running).

Comment: One requirement would be to digitally signed the executable.  The other is simply for more people to download the file.

Comment: @Ramhound How would having more people download the file help?

Comment: @Ramhound I had a look at digital signing and it seemed to cost quite a lot. This is only a temporary solution so didn't want to spend money doing that. It'd be interesting to know the answer to slhck's question as well - would they all have to download the file from the same source?

Comment: @ConorHughes - You indicated you wanted to find a way to prevent Windows from warning you about the trustworthiness of the file.  You can digitally sign code with a self-signed certificate without any costs, just requires you to trust the certificate, you created that signed to executable..

Comment: The security software considers many aspects of the executable file to make a decision.  Signing is a big one but even just having a company name, version number, etc all add up..  Applications generated with AutoIt are also commonly picked up because they just aren't seen as that legitimate, same with pytoexe type applications.  You could upload the file to Virus Total after making changes to see if you're making it less likely to false-pos.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if a program is digitally signed, Windows SmartScreen may still complain. There’s no satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

for digital signing you can try it.( reference from https://steward-fu.github.io/website/driver/wdm/self_sign.htm)
signtool get from MS SDK or Visual C++ for Python (http://aka.ms/vcpython27)

First time

`Makecert -r -pe -ss YourName YourName.cer`

`certmgr.exe -add YourName.cer -s -r localMachine root`

After

`signtool sign /s YourName YourApp.exe`